# Oracle SQL offset row number

Tags: java, sql, oracle, offset

I am trying to create a variable that can help me locating a checkpoint row, and then query the rows after that checkpoint.

At first, I was thinking of using ROWID but as the form of ROWID is non-Integer. It seem a bit inappropriate.

Regardless, one required process is to create a Rows offset which is not supported conveniently in Oracle:

I keep getting

> ORA-00904: "ITEM"."ID": invalid identifier

That variable is the Item_ID which is ID column from table ITEM.

```
select ITEM.ID,ITEM.CREATEDDATE,ITEM.TYPEID,
        CAT_DIC_AUTHOR.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_PUBLISHER.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_KEYWORD.ACCESSENTRY,CAT_DIC_KEYWORD.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE.DISPLAYENTRY,CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE.NAMEVIET,
        CAT_DIC_SH.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE.ACCESSENTRY,CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE.TYPENAME 
from ( select rownum r,ITEM.ID from ITEM) 

LEFT JOIN ITEM_AUTHOR 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_AUTHOR.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_AUTHOR 
    ON ITEM_AUTHOR.AUTHORID=CAT_DIC_AUTHOR.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_PUBLISHER 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_PUBLISHER.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_PUBLISHER 
    ON ITEM_PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERID=CAT_DIC_PUBLISHER.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_KEYWORD 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_KEYWORD.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_KEYWORD 
    ON ITEM_KEYWORD.KEYWORDID=CAT_DIC_KEYWORD.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_LANGUAGE 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_LANGUAGE.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE 
    ON ITEM_LANGUAGE.LANGUAGEID=CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_SH 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_SH.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_SH 
    ON ITEM_SH.SHID=CAT_DIC_SH.ID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE 
    ON ITEM.TYPEID=CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE.ID 

where r>100 and r<=200
```

Comment: Have you tried the `PARTITION BY` clause?

Comment: Can you post the actual string q, not just its constructing code?

Comment: @ Rachcha: I'm not very familiar with PARTITION. But it seem to be for segmenting the table base on a column value. In my case primary key is very random as well as other column.

Comment: Do you want to checkpoint the rows of the table ITEM or the rows of the big join?

Comment: I'm trying to checkpoint the table ITEM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `ITEM` word after subquery as below:

```
select ITEM.ID,ITEM.CREATEDDATE,ITEM.TYPEID,
        CAT_DIC_AUTHOR.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_PUBLISHER.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_KEYWORD.ACCESSENTRY,CAT_DIC_KEYWORD.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE.DISPLAYENTRY,CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE.NAMEVIET,
        CAT_DIC_SH.DISPLAYENTRY,
        CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE.ACCESSENTRY,CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE.TYPENAME 
from ( select rownum r,ITEM.ID,ITEM.TYPEID, ITEM.CREATEDDATE from ITEM)  ITEM

LEFT JOIN ITEM_AUTHOR 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_AUTHOR.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_AUTHOR 
    ON ITEM_AUTHOR.AUTHORID=CAT_DIC_AUTHOR.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_PUBLISHER 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_PUBLISHER.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_PUBLISHER 
    ON ITEM_PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERID=CAT_DIC_PUBLISHER.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_KEYWORD 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_KEYWORD.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_KEYWORD 
    ON ITEM_KEYWORD.KEYWORDID=CAT_DIC_KEYWORD.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_LANGUAGE 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_LANGUAGE.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE 
    ON ITEM_LANGUAGE.LANGUAGEID=CAT_DIC_LANGUAGE.ID 
LEFT JOIN ITEM_SH 
    ON ITEM.ID=ITEM_SH.ITEMID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_SH 
    ON ITEM_SH.SHID=CAT_DIC_SH.ID 
LEFT JOIN CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE 
    ON ITEM.TYPEID=CAT_DIC_ITEM_TYPE.ID 
where r>100 and r<=200
```

Comment: Thank, but now the error shift to other column "ORA-00904: "ITEM"."TYPEID": invalid identifier"